# Disable DHCP on a 2960x?

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-ios, cisco-catalyst, cisco-2960

I must start this by saying I am quite new to the IT scene. Also, I am very new to cisco switches..

I have been tasked to find out information on disabling DHCP on the cisco, and instead have the winserv in charge of dhcp.

I have found information on enabling and configuring the 2960 dhcp, however I can't seem to find info on how to turn it off?

Sorry for the noobish question, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

As with most Cisco commands, you can use the `no` form of the command to remove it. For example, `no ip dhcp pool <name>`.

You may need to set up IP helpers (DHCP relay) on some VLANs if your new DHCP server is on only one of several VLANs. For that you use the `ip helper-address <DHCP Server Address>` command on each SVI that doesn't have a DHCP server on its network.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable DHCP service on Cisco device by entering this in confuguration mode:

```
(conf-t)# no service dhcp
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have L3 interfaces, this will also stop any sort of DHCP relay service as well (i.e. DHCP relayed with the "ip helper-address" command).

Answer (score 0):

The use of show commands will be helpful as well. Do a "sho ip dhcp ?" to see them all.

"show ip DHCP binding " will show the currently allocated DHCP addresses
Once you transition your clients over to the winserver DHCP, run the show IP DHCP binding command again to make sure your switch isn't still allocating addresses.